# Python Script to read files names from a folder and copy them in txt file

Tags: python

this is code that I have written so far, it is creating the txt file but write just one name from the files in that folder. Print statements are working fine they are prinitng all the files

```
import os
path = 'C:/Users/XXX'
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files:
    print(f)
    zip_file_name = os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]
    print(zip_file_name)
    fp = open("write_demo.txt", 'w')
    print('Done Writing')
    fp.write(zip_file_name)
    fp.write("\n")
fp.close()
```

Comment: The way you are opening the file, the code throws away the old contents of the file.  You likely want to use `'a'` instead of '`'w'` to append onto the existing file contents each time through your loop.  Even better, open the file with `'w'` just once outside of the loop..

Comment: You might consider `print(zip_file_name, file=fp)` to avoid the need to add a newline.

Comment: @TimRoberts - I said that too ;)

Comment: You can also do this from a command line with `"dir /b C:\Users\XXXX > write_demo.txt"`.

Comment: open the file with 'w' just once outside of the loop worked.. thank you

Comment: Now I am seeing they are not copying in the file in the same sequence as they are listed in the folder. What can be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

As @CryptoFool stated, you are opening the file in write mode. You need append mode. See the manual for [details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

```
import os
path = 'C:/Users/XXX'
files = os.listdir(path)

for f in files:
    print(f)
    zip_file_name = os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]
    print(zip_file_name)
    fp = open("write_demo.txt", 'a')
    print('Done Writing')
    fp.write(zip_file_name)
    fp.write("\n")
fp.close()
```

Comment: You are opening the same file many times without closing it. And anyway, there is really no reason to open it more than once... Just open it once for writing ***before*** the loop

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I did. I moved the open statement fp = open("write_demo.txt", 'w') outside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example that brings together what is said in the comments, and also demonstrates how to use a `with` such that you can be sure that the file gets closed properly.  Using `with` is the much preferred way to close files.  Most notably, this will insure that the file is closed properly even when an exception is thrown inside the `with` block.

```
import os
path = 'C:/Users/XXX'
files = os.listdir(path)

with open("write_demo.txt", 'w') as fp:
    for f in files:
        print(f)
        zip_file_name = os.path.basename(f).split(".")[0]
        print(zip_file_name)
        fp.write(zip_file_name)
        fp.write("\n")
    print('Done Writing')
```

Note that `f` will contain only each file's name, not the full path to the file.  To process the file, you'd want to compute its full path with `os.path.join(path, f)`.  The fact that you are calling `basename` on `f` suggests that you think it contains the full path.  Also, the way you are taking off the extension won't work if the file 's name contains multiple `.` characters. A better way is `zip_file_name, _ = os.path.splitext(f)`.

Comment: yeah I just need the file name, not the full path as I have path mentioned in path variable. Do you still think I should use os.path.join